# IPhone 4 - IPod classic connectors

Tags: iphone, ipod, lightning

I have an iPod classic 80 GB since 2007.
I bougth a cable that allows me to stream the music from my iPod to my Pioneer car radio.

Now I would like to use the same cable for my iPhone 4, however it doesn't work.
It seems that apple changed some pins in the connector. Is that possibile?

Do you know a solution for having my iPhone 4 working as well my iPod? Maybe a simple connector adapter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, not sure, and don't quote me on this, but I don't believe the pin configuration has changed for the dock connector. Are you getting the yellow warning sign and the 'this accessory is not compatible' message on your iPhone? I found that a lot of accessories I had used with my iPod Nano and 3GS don't work with my friends 4's and 4s'.

Is the accessory one of those FM transmitters, or a direct cable link to the stereo? If it is the latter, and the radio has an 'Aux in,' you can connect up a jack to jack cable from the headphone port to your stereo. If it is the former, you may have to buy a new unit, as newer Apple devices are just not compatible with some accessories unfortunately! Griffin make a good one I believe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The accessory is just a cable connected to a special Aux output of my radio. It's not just a jack cable because it also bring the power to the iPod. However when I use it with my iPhone it doesn't charge it and neither play the music.